# Where is SQL Server Compact Edition 4?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I have Visual Studio 2010 Prof and sp1 installed. When I go to server to add new connection and create a new DB with SQL Server Compact.

There is no SQL Server Compact 4 option but 3.5?

I tried to run tools for vs2010 and SQL Server Compact which I got a need to install sp1 error which I already heave?

How do I create DB's with compact edition in vs2010?

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the SQL Server Compact Edition v4 from the [Microsoft download center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709) and install it.

It's not part of VS 2010 (since it was released after VS 2010)

**Update:** did you also download and install the [Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Tools for SQL Server Compact 4](http://erikej.blogspot.ch/2010/12/visual-studio-tools-for-sql-server.html) ?

**Update #2:** sorry, can't reproduce that issue of yours - after I've downloaded and installed those bits (SQL Server CE 4 runtime + VS 2010 tools), I do get the `SQL Server Compact 4.0` in my VS 2010 `Server Explorer > Add Connection` dialog:

[image]

Comment: yes but I have done this already downloaded this and installed it

Comment: that doesnt work http://erikej.blogspot.ch/2010/12/visual-studio-tools-for-sql-server.html    I get an error that vs2010 sp1 needs to be installed but sp1 IS installed.

Comment: What happens is that I install http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709 and but I cant install  Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Tools for SQL Server Compact 4 because I get the error need to install vs2010 sp1 but sp1 vs2010 is already installed

Comment: Some troubleshooting advice here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/03/15/sql-server-compact-4-0-tooling-support-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1-and-visual-web-developer-express-2010-sp1.aspx#FixingInstallationIssues